# Word problem -- water pipes and pool

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Three pipes 1,2 and 3 fill together a pool in 6 minutes.

Pipe 2 alone fills the pool in 75% of the time that pipe 1 alone fills a pool.

Pipe 3 alone fills a pool in 10 minutes longer than pipe 2 alone fills that pool.

In how many minutes each of the pipes fills alone that pool?

I need only the equations.

Is that correct:

$$6(\frac{1}{t}+\frac{4}{3t}+\frac{1}{\frac{3t}{4}+10})=1$$

Comment: Oh, "only that"? Well...isn't that like 95% of the work?

Comment: That looks correct, @Edo

Comment: It looks like $t$ is the time it takes pipe 1 to fill the pool in minutes.  It is good to define your variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p_1$, $p_2$, and $p_3$ be the fraction of the pool filled in one minute by pipes 1, 2, and 3, respectively. Their reciprocals $\dfrac 1{p_1}$, $\dfrac 1{p_2}$, and $\dfrac 1{p_3}$ are the times required to fill the pool (for example, if $p_1 = \dfrac 1{10}$, then one tenth of the pool is filled in one minute so it takes 10 minutes to fill).

Since pipes 1, 2, and 3 working together fill the pool in 6 minutes, they fill $\dfrac 16$ of the pool in one minute. The equation is $$p_1 + p_2 + p_3 = \frac 16.$$

Since pipe 2 fills the pool in $\dfrac 34$ of the time that pipe 1 does, you have $$ \frac 1{p_2} = \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{p_1}.$$

Since pipe 3 takes 10 mintes longer than pipe 2 you have $$\frac{1}{p_3} = \frac{1}{p_2} + 10.$$

Now you can determine $p_1$, $p_2$, and $p_3$.

Answer (score -1):

Let: 
X be the rate of the first pipe (in pool/minutes) 
Y be the rate of the second pipe (in pool/minutes) 
Z be the rate of the third pipe (in pool/minutes) 
t be the time in minutes for the first pipe, X, to fill the pool 
$$X = \frac{1}{t} , Y = \frac{1}{(\frac{3}{4})t} , Z = \frac{1}{(\frac{3}{4})t + 10}$$
$$X + Y + Z = \frac{1}{6}$$
$$\frac{1}{t} + \frac{1}{(\frac{3}{4})t} + \frac{1}{(\frac{3}{4})t + 10} = \frac{1}{6}$$
$$\frac{1}{t} + \frac{4}{3t} + \frac{4}{3t + 40} = \frac{1}{6}$$
Multiplying by 3t, we get: 

$$3 + 4 + (4 * 3t) / (3t + 40) = 3t/6$$
Multiplying by (3t + 40), we get:
$$9t + 120 + 12t + 160 + 12t = 3t * (3t + 40)/6$$
$$33t + 280 = (9t^2 + 120t)/6$$
$$198t + 1680 = 9t^2 + 120t$$
$$9t^2 - 78t -1680 = 0$$

Then, use the quadratic formula to solve for t.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).